# multiple mysql linked grids with EditableGrid

Tags: jquery, datagrid, editablegrid

I am working through the EditableGrid demos modifying the code to understand it and reach a working example of multiple grids with the write-to-db example. I am a non-programmer and vba-hack.

Creating multiple grids in non-db examples is simple enough. However trying to replicate the code/structure for multiple grids I think *prototype* and *this* objects are might be confusing me

multiple grids without the db-link/inline-edit:

```
        window.onload = function() {
            editableGrid = new EditableGrid("DemoGridMinimal"); 
            editableGrid.tableLoaded = function() { this.renderGrid("tablecontent", "testgrid"); };
            editableGrid.loadXML("grid.xml");
            editableGrid = new EditableGrid("DemoGridMinimal2"); 
            editableGrid.tableLoaded = function() { this.renderGrid("tablecontent2", "testgrid"); };
            editableGrid.loadXML("grid.xml");
        }
```

single grid with the db link and inline edit: (a little modified from the example)

```
function DatabaseGrid() { 
    this.editableGrid = new EditableGrid("demo", {
        enableSort: false,
        tableLoaded: function() { datagrid.initializeGrid(this); },
        modelChanged: function(rowIndex, columnIndex, oldValue, newValue, row) {
            updateCellValue(this, rowIndex, columnIndex, oldValue, newValue, row);
        }
    });
    this.fetchGrid();   
}

DatabaseGrid.prototype.initializeGrid = function(grid) { grid.renderGrid("tablecontent", "testgrid"); };  
DatabaseGrid.prototype.fetchGrid = function() { this.editableGrid.loadXML("loaddata.php"); }; 

window.onload = function() { 
    datagrid = new DatabaseGrid();
};
```

if it helps put overall context, the end result is to have several grids on a single page, populated with single sql query, defined by a html form input {accounting sql injection}, with each grid showing different fields from the db

could someone be kind enough to briefly explain the context of *prototype* and *this* in the example here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

done courtesy of freelancer.com.

with a "function DatabaseGrid()" to create each grid, a PHP call for each grid to populate them and a "$(document).ready(function()" listing each successive grid so each one loads on the webpage